# 'Table does not exists' error when trying to call a CTN and storing the query in a variable

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I'm working on a practice MySQL problem that involves pivoting the table. I wanted the query to be as general a possible, so I opted to use dynamic pivoting.

Below is my code:

```
/* Change depending on table names */
WITH t AS (SELECT OCCUPATION AS Header FROM OCCUPATIONS GROUP BY OCCUPATION 
       ORDER BY FIELD(OCCUPATION,'Doctor', 'Professor', 'Singer', 'Actor')),

     t2 AS (SELECT NAME As Entries, OCCUPATION As Header, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OCCUPATION ORDER BY NAME) AS ID FROM OCCUPATIONS)

/* Dynamic pivoting code */
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(' MAX(IF(Header = ''', t.Header ,''', Entries, NULL)) AS ',t.Header))
INTO @PivotQuery FROM t;

SET @PivotQuery = CONCAT(' SELECT ', @PivotQuery, ' FROM t2 GROUP BY ID');

PREPARE statement FROM @PivotQuery;
EXECUTE statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
```

When I execute this, I get this error. 'ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 12: Table 't2' doesn't exist'

The only way I can make the code work is by doing it like this:

```
/* Change depending on table names */
WITH t AS (SELECT OCCUPATION AS Header FROM OCCUPATIONS GROUP BY OCCUPATION 
       ORDER BY FIELD(OCCUPATION,'Doctor', 'Professor', 'Singer', 'Actor'))
       
/* Dynamic pivoting code */
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(' MAX(IF(Header = ''', t.Header ,''', Entries, NULL)) AS ',t.Header))
INTO @PivotQuery FROM t;

SET @PivotQuery = CONCAT(' SELECT ', @PivotQuery, ' FROM 
                         
                         /* Declared t2 here instead */
                         (SELECT NAME As Entries, OCCUPATION As Header, 
                          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OCCUPATION ORDER BY NAME) AS ID
                          FROM OCCUPATIONS)
                         /* End of Declaration */
                         
                         t2 GROUP BY ID');

PREPARE statement FROM @PivotQuery;
EXECUTE statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
```

I wonder why the 2nd query is not able to call t2 when the first query is able to call t?
Also, is there a way I can declare t2 at the beginning and not at the middle of the supposed to be general code?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. I don't fully understand well but the CTE exists only during the duration of the query after it. So for the next query, CTN t2 no longer exists. I opted to use temporary tables instead and got what I wanted.
Here's the code:

```
/* Change depending on table names */
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t AS 
    (SELECT NAME As Entries, OCCUPATION As Header, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OCCUPATION ORDER BY NAME) AS ID
     FROM OCCUPATIONS);

WITH o AS (SELECT OCCUPATION AS Header FROM OCCUPATIONS GROUP BY OCCUPATION 
       ORDER BY FIELD(OCCUPATION,'Doctor', 'Professor', 'Singer', 'Actor'))
       
/* Dynamic pivoting code */
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(' MAX(IF(Header = ''', o.Header ,''', Entries, NULL)) AS ',o.Header))
INTO @PivotQuery FROM o;

SET @PivotQuery = CONCAT(' SELECT ', @PivotQuery, ' FROM t GROUP BY ID');

PREPARE statement FROM @PivotQuery;
EXECUTE statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
```